# Haskell - Merge Sort, sorting words and numbers

Tags: haskell, mergesort

I've written a merge sort in Haskell, it works when using numbers but not with words, and I thought it would. I just get "Not in scope" when using words and letters. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x <= y = x : merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys

mergeSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort [] = []
mergeSort [x] = [x]
mergeSort xs
    = merge (mergeSort top) (mergeSort bottom)
    where
    (top, bottom) = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

Comment: This works fine with Strings, f.e. `mergeSort ["banana", "candy", "apple"]`

Comment: Your code looks okay. It could be helpful to see the exact input and the complete error message. It is not exactly helpful that *something* is not in scope...

Answer (score 4):

Are you entering your words like this?

```
[this,is,an,example,sentence]
```

The syntax is not correct. If you want to input a literal string, you have to encapsulte it in double quotes (`"`):

```
["this","is","an","example","sentence"]
```

If that is not your error, feel free to ignore this answer.

Comment: To be sure, the syntax is correct, that's why he gets a "not in scope" error and not a syntax error.

Comment: @Ingo Of course the syntax is formally correct, but it's not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine.

However I'd suggest to split the list in one pass, without using `length`. Of course, the order isn't important here, just that we have two lists of about the same size. You could do it that way:

```
splitList [] = ([],[])
splitList [x] = ([x],[])
splitList (x:y:zs) = let (xs,ys) = splitList zs in (x:xs, y:ys)
```

... or tail recursive ...

```
splitList zs = go zs [] [] where
   go [] xs ys = (xs, ys)
   go [x] xs ys = (x:xs, ys)
   go (x:y:zs) xs ys = go zs (x:xs) (y:ys)
```

... or using indexes ...

```
splitList xs = (go even, go odd) where
   go f = map snd $ filter (f.fst) $ indexed
   indexed = zip [0..] xs
```

... or using a fold ...

```
import Data.List

splitList zs = snd $ foldl' go (True,([],[])) zs where
   go (True,(xs,ys)) x = (False,(x:xs,ys))   
   go (False,(xs,ys)) x = (True,(xs,x:ys))
```

Comment: As pointed out to me on #haskell when I suggested a similar solution, there is a tradeoff: with this solution, the sort is not stable.

Comment: Well, then calculate the length of the original list once. Then pass in the length of the lists you send to the helpers, which can be done with a simple division by 2 operation. I personally think the approach where you map each element of the original list to a singleton list is cool.